# $f issue for flowpalyer plugin on iphone & ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using `flowplayer` for video play on my website but i found there is a error for iphone & ipad devices so after googling i get a way for iphone video player but it is show error I am confuse about the `use of $f.`

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined(anonymous function) @ flowplayer.ipad-3.2.13.js:11
```

**TEST HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer.ipad-3.2.13.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<a href="http://stream.flowplayer.org/flowplayer-700.mp4" class="player"
   id="player">
</a>
<p>
Video courtesy of 
<a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try including also regular flowplayer.js script ?

Comment: Yes I also try with that it is not working ,  but I didn't understand that $f meaning ?